# If $0\leqslant X\leqslant T$ (where $T$ is a positive constant that exceeds $u=EX$), show that $\operatorname{Var}(X) \leqslant u(T-u)$.

Tags: probability, statistics

If $0\leqslant X \leqslant T$ (where T is a positive constant that exceeds $u=EX$), show that $\operatorname{Var}(X) \leqslant u(T-u)$.

I have the proof down to $E[X^2] \leqslant TE[X]$ but don't know how to proceed from there. Any help? Thank you in advance.

Comment: $\text{Var}(X) = E[X^2] - E[X]^2$, where $u = E[X]$.

Answer (score 1):

Bounding $X\leq T$ in the formulation of the variance gives
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Var}[X]&=\mathbb E[X^2]-\mathbb E[X]^2\\
&\leq \mathbb E[XT]-\mathbb E[X]^2\\
&=u(T-u)
\end{align*}
note that this can be achieved by only one distribution : $\mathbb P[X=0]=1-u/T$ and $\mathbb P[X=T]=u/T$.